# Adding length to my for loop program

Tags: python, string-length

I have created a program on pycharm which allows the user to input a number so a list of items can be created. The program is as follows:

```
item = int(input("How many items do you want in your list? "))
stringList = []
for i in range(1, item +1):
    stringList.append(input("Enter String {0}: ".format(i)))
print(stringList)
```

An example of what could be output shows as follows:

```
How many items do you want in your list? 3
Enter String 1: apple
Enter String 2: banana
Enter String 3: grape
['apple', 'banana', 'grape']
```

What I'm wanting to do now is to add the length of each string that has been typed by the user. I am fairly new to python and was wondering how one would add the length so the output would be something like this:

```
Enter String 1: apple
Enter String 2: banana
Enter String 3: grape
['apple', 'banana', 'grape']
The length of the string 'apple' is 5
The length of the string 'banana' is 6
The length of the string 'grape' is 5
The total length of all strings is 21
```

Comment: What has thou tried? I can confirm, it is possible.

Comment: I tried a number of different things. I have been sitting here for the past two hours trying different things however I haven't come close to figuring it out. Brains on overload at the moment. Like I said I am fairly new to the whole programing and everything and I really appreciate the feedback I'm getting.

Comment: If you've tried a number of things then the most relevant thing you could include in your post is the things you have tried => what is not working => why _you think_ your attempt is not working. Rather than just keep repeating that you're new to programming and appreciate help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, will know for next time

Answer (score 0):

Use `len(string_var)`

This will return the length of string `string_var`

You can add in your code like:

```
for i in range(1, item +1):
    stringList.append(input("Enter String {0}: ".format(i)))
print(stringList)

total_str_length = 0

for each_string in stringList:
     print("The length of the string '%s' is %s") %(each_string, len(each_string))
     total_str_length += len(each_string)

print("The total length of all strings is %s") % total_str_length
```

This will print the each string in stringList formatted as expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I ended up with after tweaking the feedback given:

```
item = int(input("How many items do you want in your list? "))
itemnum = []
for i in range(1, item +1):
    itemnum.append(input("Enter String {0}: ".format(i)))
print(itemnum)

totalLength = 0

for eachString in itemnum:
    print("The length of the string",(eachString), "is :", len(eachString))
    totalLength += len(eachString)
print("The total length of all strings is:", totalLength)
```

The out put was:

```
How many items do you want in your list? 4
Enter String 1: red
Enter String 2: blue
Enter String 3: green
Enter String 4: yellow
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
The length of the string red is : 3
The length of the string blue is : 4
The length of the string green is : 5
The length of the string yellow is : 6
The total length of all strings is: 18
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Manish is easiest to understand, but as a one line solution, you could do this, which adds everything together after you've built the list:

```
total_length = sum(len(word) for word in stringList)
```